# Start onedrive.exe in silent mode?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I need to periodically restart `onedrive.exe`, and I believe a Scheduled Task is appropriate for this problem to kill and then start the process.

However, when `onedrive.exe` starts this way, I get the welcome message in my notification bar, as well as the OneDrive folder opens, which I would like to avoid. How could I start `onedrive.exe` in "silent mode"? Is there a command line parameter for this? Documentation is really lacking on this one.

> **Note:** `onedrive.exe` is located at
>   `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe`

**How could I start `onedrive.exe` so that the welcome message and OneDrive folder do not open as well?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I looked into msconfig.exe where OneDrive starts automatically on booting (if activated).

You could realize it with an optional parameter: the `/background` parameter starts OneDrive without any tooltip popup and without opening OneDrive folder in Windows Explorer.

FYI: You could use `%LocalAppData%` instead of `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local`

Comment: It seems command-line switch /background solution no longer works. There also seems to be a dearth of information on the Microsoft website.  Is there another way to launch OneDrive in the background?  Thanks, doug